# attributeSetDefinitions REST-API returns 404 Not Found

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, contact

I'm not able to get a *attributeSetDefinitions* response from the REST-API using eg. `GET /contacts/v1/schemas/c064556a-71a2-e511-96fe-38eaa7142c61/attributeSetDefinitions`.
I get a 404 Not Found.

I'm using the documentation here: https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/rest-api/v1/contacts/retrieveAttributeSetDefinitions.html

First I use the schemaID I got from `GET /contacts/v1/schemas`.
But somehow none of the schemaIDs in the response works in the attributeSetDefinitions-endpoint.

Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alas, the documentation appears to be incorrect. You can't appear to get Attribute Set Definitions by schema.

The correct route to use is:

```
GET https://www.exacttargetapis.com/contacts/v1/attributeSetDefinitions
```

This will return all Attribute Set Definitions in your Contact Model

You can then retrieve information for an individual Attribute Set Definition by using the route:

```
GET https://www.exacttargetapis.com/contacts/v1/attributeSetDefinitions/{{id}}
```

Where `{{id}}` is an Attribute Set Definition Id returned in the previous step (however the previous step displays all Attribute Set Definitions so you probably don't need this).

Comment: I don't work for Salesforce, but I know someone on the documentation team who does, so I'll let them know about this.

Comment: The documentation is still incorrect. See [attributeSetDefinitions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/retrieveAttributeSetDefinitionsID.htm)

Comment: I tried using  **GET https://www.exacttargetapis.com/contacts/v1/attributeSetDefinitions/{{id}}**, but it rather returned the whole set of Attribute Set Definitions as in **GET https://www.exacttargetapis.com/contacts/v1/attributeSetDefinitions**
This one returned filtered result though **https://www.exacttargetapis.com/contacts/v1/attributeSetDefinitions/name:{myName}**