# Get a list of all Attribute Sets in Contact Builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, contactbuilder

I need to get a list of all available Attribute Sets in Contact Builder. Currently I use the following REST API resource:

```
Host: https://www.exacttargetapis.com
GET /contacts/v1/attributeSetDefinitions
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

[GET /contacts/v1/attributeSetDefinitions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/retrieveAttributeSetDefinitions.htm)

**This returns a huge payload in multiple pages** (if there are many Attribute Sets in your account), **which is not very efficient** since I don't need all that data. I only need Names/IDs of Attribute Sets. If I need details on a particular Attribute Set I would use another REST API resource:

```
Host: https://www.exacttargetapis.com
GET /contacts/v1/attributeSetDefinitions/name:{name}
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

[GET /contacts/v1/attributeSetDefinitions/name:{name}](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/retrieveAttributeSetDefinitionsID.htm)

**QUESTION:**

Is there a more light-weight way to get a list of all Attribute Sets registered in Contact Builder?

**P.S.** Although I have not found any other [REST API resource](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/routes.htm) that would serve this purpose, yet I am asking this question because the SFMC documentation is not always correct and up-to-date ([example](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/136826/attributesetdefinitions-rest-api-returns-404-not-found/136908#comment292788_136908)).